# Hide Excel Pivot items

Tags: excel, pivot

I'm trying to find a way to hide some of the items in a pivot table that are not in the total summary. See an example below:

[image]

See also structure pivot fields with the highlighted fields I don't need to show the values except on the totals.

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange fields like this:

[image: Data]

At present you have Product line for example included in rows which is splitting out your total. You need to remove these until you get the desired view. Report layout is tabular and subtotals are off.

Comment: Thanks QHarr, very helpfull